# Align rows elements in the tabular form

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a problem with the the aligning of a `tabular`.
I used the code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}||m{1.5cm}|m{1.5cm}|}
\hline
1& 2 & 7 & 8 \\
0 & 89 & 100 & 55\\
4 & 6  & 4999& 055\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

and I want the elements centered. What command I should use?

Comment: do you really want centering here? It is more normal to make numeric columns be aligned so that the digits are in vertical columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for the `m`-type columns, since they're intended for *vertical* alignment of cell contents. You seem to be interested in a centred `p`-type column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}} }
    \toprule
    1 &  2 &   7  &  8  \\
    0 & 89 &  100 &  55 \\
    4 &  6 & 4999 & 055 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The above suggests a number of things:

1. Using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for tabular presentation;
2. Use a short-hand notation for duplicate column specifications: `*{<num>}{<col spec>}`; and
3. Using [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) to insert content with every cell in a column with the notation `>{<before>}` (or `<{<after>}`).

---

If you're into aligning numbers at the least significant digit, then consider using [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \sisetup{table-column-width=15mm}
  \begin{tabular}{
      S[table-format=1]%    x
      S[table-format=2]%   xx
      S[table-format=4]% xxxx
      S[table-format=3]%  xxx
    }
    \toprule
    1 &  2 &    7 &   8 \\
    0 & 89 &  100 &  55 \\
    4 &  6 & 4999 & 055 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Note that `0`-prefixes in numbers are removed (which it should).

Comment: I would tend to write `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}<{}}` and then `\begin{tabular}{CCCC}` but otherwise I fully agree.

Comment: I do not understand how can 
Iadd columns?

Comment: @VanityFair: You can add columns around my `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` specification. Or, you can increase `<num>` to set the number of columns you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ *4{C{1.5cm}} }% or { C{1.5cm} C{1.5cm} ... }
            \toprule
            1 &  2 &   7  &  8  \\
            0 & 89 &  100 &  55 \\
            4 &  6 & 4999 & 055 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```